# How can I save the result of nltk.chunk.ne_chunk as a list?

Tags: nlp, nltk, chunks

How can I save the result of the function nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged) into a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are after this:

```
result = list(nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged))
```

The recognizer returns a “generator”, from which you could fetch output a little at a time (great with a huge dataset), or collect all the output by turning it into a list as above.